# How did this git repo become out of sync and how can I fix it?

Tags: git

My Mac had a hardware failure, so I transferred a git repository (a folder with all of the files including the .git file) to a Debian machine. From that Debian machine, I made a commit and pushed to origin/master (on Github) and made some uncommitted changes to files after that.

After repairing the Mac, I transferred this repo (including uncommitted changes) from Debian back to the Mac. Then I made a commit on the Mac. Git (via 'git status') is reporting that I am three commits ahead of origin/master. But if I compare the commit history on the Mac and on Github, I am actually only one commit ahead.

I'm afraid to do a push to origin/master without damaging something. Can I correct the local repo to being one commit ahead as it should be, or will a push fix itself?

Comment: You could try pushing to a different branch and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just branch your local `master` into a temporary branch and reset the state of `master` locally:

```
git branch temporary master     # create a local branch called 'temporary' based on master
git checkout master             # checkout master if you haven't already
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master    # reset it to origin
```

Now look at the history (you're on `master`) and make sure it's correct. If it isn't, and the temporary branch was correct:

```
git checkout -B master temporary    # reset master branch to temporary's state
```